# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I am new for android studio and I am getting following error. I have checked many links and try but problem is as it is.

```
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':paisaBazar:dexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

My main gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paisabazaar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        compileOptions {

            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile project(':main')
        compile project(':datetimepickerlibrary')
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

module build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        compileOptions {

            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Module2 build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}
```

please help me to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove  compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar') and use the maven dependency instead of the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Please add this inside android block in your app gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Edited : 
Try this also.

```
configurations {
    dependencies {
        compile(project(':Android-SDK')) {
            compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
    }
}
```

It solved mine one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. By adding the following lines to the `build.gradle` file located in platforms/android I was able to fix it:

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

I copied it after the line:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```